# Why do papers fly off the wall when you run past?

Tags: aerodynamics

Another example is walking past a book and the pages of the book will fly forward. When you run, why do you blow air to knock over papers off the wall or turn pages of a book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run or walk, you create turbulence in the air around you, particularly behind you, in your wake.  The faster you go, the more turbulence is produced. The human form (usually) is not the most aerodynamic structure in nature.

This turbulence causes anything that is not heavy and not fixed down to move.

The following diagram is a model of the turbulence in the wake of a person walking:

[image]

Image source and further images of simulations and calculations from the article [Computational Study of the Wake
and Contaminant Transport of a
Walking Human](http://www.pawsoflife.org/Library/Scent/Edge_Settles_HumanWake.pdf) (Edge et al. 2005), from the article, the dotted lines and arrows represent

> artistic sketches of the bulk
>   characteristics of the observed wake

The middle diagram below show a general idea of what is happening with the air flow around someone in motion (in this case, running) indicated by the arrows:

[image]

(*[Image Source](http://www.practicallyscience.com/category/running/)*)

Comment: So you form a vortex behind you when you run and that's what knocks that papers off the walls.

Comment: A very turbulent one, yes - I am just going to add another image.

Comment: What are those dotted lines for?

Comment: The dotted lines are sketched outlines of the turbulent air flow discussed in the paper linked

Comment: Its kind of like an aircraft wing. An aircraft wing forms a powerful wing tip vortex and the more speed= more powerful vortex.

Comment: Yes, that is the first thing that crossed my mind as well